# How to check whether columns of a matrix follow a predetermined order in R?

Tags: r

The matrix would look like...

```
      [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]  
 [1,] "notB" "notB" "B"    "notB" "notB"
 [2,] "notB" "notB" "notB" "notB" "notB"
 [3,] "notB" "notB" "notB" "notB" "notB"
 [4,] "B"    "notB" "notB" "notB" "B"   
 [5,] "notB" "notB" "notB" "notB" "notB"
 [6,] "notB" "B"    "B"    "notB" "B"   
 [7,] "notB" "notB" "notB" "B"    "notB"
 [8,] "B"    "B"    "B"    "B"    "B"   
 [9,] "B"    "B"    "notB" "B"    "notB"
```

and the idea is to count (in the setting of thousands of columns), how many keep the "B" elements together, in whichever position, e.g. `B B B notB notB notB notB notB notB`, or  `notB notB   B B B   notB notB notB notB`.

In the matrix posted above, only column `[,4]` fulfills the criteria of the `B`s being "together".

---

Here is the code to generate the matrix:

```
b=c(rep("B", 3), rep("notB", 6))
n = 1000
d = replicate(n,sample(b, replace=F))
```

Comment: So you want to know in which columns you can find "B" next to another "B"?

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you are asking.  As written it is not clear what your question is.

Comment: @BrianD I edited the OP.

Comment: @Toni Oh, so you want to find all columns where ALL of the "B"s are consecutive?  Columns 1 and 2 also have two B's together (in rows 8 and 9) but another B that is separate

Comment: Count the total number of B's in the column.  count the number of consecutive Bs, if the numbers are the same, you got it.

Comment: Please provide the code for generating your example matrix.  The question should provide all the code necessary for a minimum reproducible example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another method:

```
apply(mat,2, function(c) all(diff(which(c=="B")) == 1))
```

Here we `apply` a function to each column that checks to see if `all` the `diff`terence between the indices of the elements corresponding to `"B"` is `1`. This condition holds if and only if all the `"B"`'s are together.

Using your posted data this gives:

```
##   V1    V2    V3    V4    V5 
##FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

We can then use `which` to extract the column for which this is true:

```
which(apply(mat,2, function(c) all(diff(which(c=="B")) == 1)))
## V4
##  4
```

Or, as @IaroslavDomin commented, we can instead `apply` the function

```
apply(mat, 2, function(c){w <- which(c == "B"); length(w) == diff(range(w)) + 1})
```

This has the elegance that we do not have to check to see that all diffs for adjoining indices for `"B"`'s are `1`. Instead, we just have to check that the difference between the last and first of these (i.e., `diff(range(w))` plus 1) matches the number of `"B"`'s in the column.

**Data:**

```
mat <- structure(c("notB", "notB", "notB", "B", "notB", "notB", "notB", 
"B", "B", "notB", "notB", "notB", "notB", "notB", "B", "notB", 
"B", "B", "B", "notB", "notB", "notB", "notB", "B", "notB", "B", 
"notB", "notB", "notB", "notB", "notB", "notB", "notB", "B", 
"B", "B", "notB", "notB", "notB", "B", "notB", "B", "notB", "B", 
"notB"), .Dim = c(9L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("V1", "V2", 
"V3", "V4", "V5")))
      V1     V2     V3     V4     V5    
 [1,] "notB" "notB" "B"    "notB" "notB"
 [2,] "notB" "notB" "notB" "notB" "notB"
 [3,] "notB" "notB" "notB" "notB" "notB"
 [4,] "B"    "notB" "notB" "notB" "B"   
 [5,] "notB" "notB" "notB" "notB" "notB"
 [6,] "notB" "B"    "B"    "notB" "B"   
 [7,] "notB" "notB" "notB" "B"    "notB"
 [8,] "B"    "B"    "B"    "B"    "B"   
 [9,] "B"    "B"    "notB" "B"    "notB"
```

Comment: Or we can use `function(c){w <- which(c == "B"); length(w) == diff(range(w)) + 1}`. Which would be faster in general case, when we may have lots of "B". But in this case, with only 3 "B" per column, your seems faster.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And +1. I used it successfully.

Comment: @IaroslavDomin: Thank you for your comment; very elegant.

Comment: An alternative to the `diff(range())` approach that seems interesting is `tmat = t(mat == "B"); (max.col(tmat, "last") - max.col(tmat, "first") + 1L) == rowSums(tmat)`

Answer (score 3):

Here is one method using `rle` in base R.

```
myMat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,] "B"  "B"  "B"  "B"  "B"  "B"  "B"  "B"  "B"  "B"  
[2,] "NB" "B"  "NB" "B"  "NB" "B"  "B"  "NB" "NB" "NB" 
[3,] "NB" "NB" "B"  "B"  "NB" "B"  "NB" "B"  "B"  "B"  
[4,] "NB" "NB" "NB" "B"  "NB" "NB" "NB" "NB" "B"  "NB" 
[5,] "NB" "NB" "B"  "B"  "NB" "B"  "NB" "NB" "NB" "B"  
[6,] "NB" "NB" "B"  "B"  "B"  "NB" "NB" "B"  "NB" "NB"
```

With this example matrix, columns 1, 2, 4, and 7 have the Bs together. All of the other columns have Bs separated by NBs.

```
myRLEs <- apply(myMat, 2, rle)
which(sapply(myRLEs, function(x) sum(x$values == "B") == 1))
[1] 1 2 4 7
```

The first line calculates the run lengths of Bs and NBs along the columns and returns a list containing this information. The second line, `sum(x$values == "B") == 1` checks that there is only one instance of "B", and `sapply` applies this check across each element of myRLEs. `which` returns the positions where this check holds.

**data**

```
set.seed(1234)
myMat <- matrix(sample(c("B", "NB"), 60, replace=TRUE), 6)
```

Comment: The code would be `b=c(rep("B", 3), rep("NB", 6)); n = 1000; d = replicate(n,sample(b, replace=F))`.

Comment: @Toni Add this comment as text directly into your question. Don't add it as a comment. Also, don't forget to use `set.seed` so people can reproduce it.

Comment: Done. Thank you. If you wouldn't mind tweaking the answer accordingly, I'd would like to accept it.

Comment: In all fairness, the other answer provides me with a way of doing what I need without resorting to th e`rle` package. So I will up-vote your answer, but accept the other one.

Comment: @Toni Sounds great to me. That answer is probably more efficient. Just note that `rle` is a base R function, ie doesn't require any packages.